# I was brought back to life after being frozen in time, how do I know if I'm a copy of my original consciousness or if I'm actually the real me?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, consciousness, future

Year 2038, I died and was frozen for almost two centuries.

They managed to bring my flesh and bone back to life but is my consciousness the same?

What if my real self died forever? What if my consciousness was born the moment my body was brought back to life, complete with all my memories?

More like the theories that the world was created 5 minutes ago in the actual state.

But now it applies to me, how do I know if I was reborn or copied and pasted?

Please refrain from religious and spiritual answers.

Comment: It would be hard to refrain from religious and spiritual answers. From what I recall, science still hasn't definitive answer what is consciousness.

Comment: I would close this question as too broad and opinion-based. To be able to check "consciousness" version you need to define what "consciousness" is. And in worlbuilding - why it is imporant.

Comment: Why does it matter you were dead for 200 years? Let me rephrase: when you wake up in the morning, why aren't you anxious about whether you are a copy or real you?

Comment: Do I even have a real self?

Comment: this q belongs more on philosophy.se than here.

Comment: Ummm, I believe it is called paranoid schizophrenia. How do you differentiate between the two?

Comment: How do you know that "you" dont die every time you go to sleep? As soon as the "thread of consciousness" is cut (be it sleep, death, or drugs), all bets are off and we really have no clue what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, there could have been so much more to the question if it were to be set up in a Philip-K-Dick-ensian context.

Let's put some structure in the question, shall we?
For a starter, let's handwave the Absolute Reality in the picture and define the "objective" as "consistent with the Absolute Reality, in no way contradicted by it".

Now, as long your consciousness it objectively in sync with the Absolute Reality, then [you can't tell](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/169764/26061)  if you is you or a copy, and [it won't matter either way](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/169766/26061). Your anxiety is nothing more than that: an anxiety. A not so rare affliction that affects humans and for which treatments exist even nowadays.

The problem starts when you consciousness and your experience of the Absolute Reality diverge. Like:

- you are contacted by a huge African American with black sunnies and a leather long coat that offers you two pills [to crush and snort](https://xkcd.com/566/) (eww). Then you know there is someone fucking with you perception of the absolute reality. The good news is that you'll learn Kung-fu;
- your girlfriend, Donna, reveals she's a narcotic agent and not a drug dealer. You've been fed too much substance D and both your consciousnesses and experience of the Absolute Reality are double-fucked; nothing to be anxious about, though, you can jump straight into panic mode. Maybe you'll find blue flowers later, maybe not, Bruce;
- you keep finding those strange coins with the face of your employer, Runciter, and ads about deodorant spray cans pop up now and then. It means you are still in cryopreservation and none of the Absolute Reality, your perception of it or your consciousness matter anyway, you're still dead (and I'm alive)

<sup>(see how a bit of context makes a good story from your otherwise irrelevant anxiety?)
If only there'd be a site to help you start building worlds - welcome here, Kyu</sup>

Answer (score 5):

You don't.

Unless your worldbuilding includes a way to copy and paste a consciousness but also hast certain side-effects that make it recongizable for the copyed consciousness that it is only a copy.

If the copy is perfect, then there is no way ANYONE could tell it apart from the original.

But even if it is not perfect, it might still be hard for the copy to tell whether it is a copy or not.

For example: Let's say some of the memories are copied wrong. The copy still has no way to find out it is a copy. Only someone else who knows how the memories are supposed to be can detect the error and maybe conclude that he or she is dealing with a copy.

It is just the same as with the idea of the boltzmann brain, or the universe being created 5 seconds ago in just this exact state, there is no way for us to disprove them. We can only decide for us, that these questions are nonsensical, that the only reasonabel thing to assume is that the universe was not created 5 seconds ago, that we actually exist and so on.

Answer (score 2):

My counter question is, does it really matter?

You are you, brought back from the dead. Hopefully you died from being frozen, otherwise your body won't be very usable, even after reanimation.

With a bit of luck, you are the only you in existence, if you are not, then there is your answer. You aren't really you, because there is more than one of you.

But back to my original statement, does it matter? If somehow someone or something is abusing your past or memories to get you to do their bidding, then yes, you should ask the question of your memories are real. In any other case, you can go about living your continued life however you like. In essence, you are you. You are the one that exists in that moment in time, with the memories you have. Whether the memories are real or not, or the body is, does not matter, it can't be changed anyway. It will practically change nothing in your life apart from sending you into an unnecessary existential crisis.

The only way you will find out is by asking whomever resurrected you, and hope you can trust them. But I wouldn't do that, unless you have no other choice.

Comment: "A difference that makes no difference, *is* no difference." -- Korzybski